# How can a man kill his sexual desires or desires towards women?

Tags: women, sex

How can a man kill his sexual desires or desires towards women ?

Comment: how do child stop playing with toys when they grow up?

Comment: it cannot be dont by one practice it is by intense effort and love of krishna one can comeout. 1. Ekadashi Fasting 2. Chaturmasya vrata(avoid one item permonth as stated in varaha purana) 3. be in the presence of holy man and serving them. 4. listening to past life time of Sri Krishna 5. Mediatating 6. constant japa morning, midday and evening. 6. Living near ganges taking bath 3 times remember foot of sri hari. Overall Avoid taking excessive food. (No onion and garlic is a must). Avoid outside food.

Comment: I will respectfully disagree with everyone here (what’s new hahaha) to say I’m not entirely sure this is necessary. I think can actually do more damage than good to many people. I think there are numerous multiple & misunderstandings and interpolations w/ respect to some larger issues in the religious texts, sex being one of them. Lotsa messed-up views and notions on this imo.

Comment: Also not to be misandrist but the texts are written from viewpoint of men. What abt girls who are tempted by guys ? Or gender fluid people, gay ppl, or trans folks or same sex attractions etc ? There are people of all types trying to read religious texts and trying to understand how to deal with all kinds of this stuff. But in general I think so much misunderstandings around these topics.

Answer (score 3):

One should divert all his senses towards Lord.

- Do not get **drowned in delusion by going wild with passions and lust
  by seeing a woman's navel and chest. These are nothing but a
  modification of flesh.** Do not fail to remember this again and again
  in your mind.(Bhajagovindam 3)
- The childhood is lost by attachment to playfulness. **Youth is lost by
  attachment to woman.** Old age passes away by thinking over many past
  things. But there is hardly anyone who wants to be lost in
  parabrahmam. Who is your wife ? Who is your son ? Strange is this
  samsara. Of whom are you ? From where have you come ? Brother, ponder
  over these truths here. **From Satsangh comes non-attachment, from
  non-attachment comes freedom from delusion, which leads to
  self-settledness. From self-settledness comes Jeevan Mukti. What good
  is lust when youth has fled ? What use is a lake which has no water ?**
  Where are the relatives when wealth is gone ? Where is samsara when
  the Truth is known ? Do not boast of wealth, friends, and youth. Each
  one of these are destroyed within a minute. Free yourself from the
  illusion of the world of Maya and attain the timeless Truth.
  (Bhajagovindam 7-11)
- A yogī should similarly meditate on the most benevolent smile of
  Lord Śrī Hari, a smile which, for all those who bow to Him, dries
  away the ocean of tears caused by intense grief. The yogī should
  also meditate on the **Lord’s arched eyebrows, which are manifested by
  His internal potency in order to charm the sex-god for the good of
  the sages**. (SB 3.28.32)

> Commentary says The **charming brows of the Supreme Personality of
> Godhead protect the sages and devotees from being charmed by material
> lust and sex attraction.** Yāmunācārya, a great ācārya, said that ever
> **since he had seen the charming pastimes of the Lord, the charms of sex life had become abominable for him**, and the mere thought of sex
> enjoyment would cause him to spit and turn his face. Thus if anyone
> wants to be **aloof from sex attraction, he must see the charming
> smile and fascinating eyebrows of the Supreme Personality of
> Godhead.**

- These inauspicious disturbances can be gradually removed by constant
  remembrance of Me, by **congregational hearing and chanting of My
  holy names**, or by following in the footsteps of the great masters
  of yoga. (SB 11.28.40)

> Commentary says According to Śrīla Śrīdhara Svāmī, by **meditation on
> the Supreme Lord one can overcome lust and other mental
> disturbances**, and by following in the footsteps of great
> transcendentalists one can overcome hypocrisy, false pride and other
> types of mental imbalance.

Answer (score 1):

Surrender to God (Krishna). Read atleast one shloka a day and try to follow the teachings and apply in life.

For your question from Chapter 6 verse : 14

> Thus, with a serene, fearless, and unwavering mind, and staunch in the
> vow of celibacy, the vigilant yogi should meditate on Me, having Me
> alone as the supreme goal.

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6/verse/14